# Magento2: Issue with load more products

Tags: magento2, ajax

We have any issue with load more products (no load photo product).

Please on down page click "load more".

```
https://gerris.pl/new-arrivals
```

Any solution?

Comment: Because you are loading through AJAX your image load system isn't being called

Comment: Do you have any solution? on other pages auto load products ajax work correct

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791740/jquery-lazyload-with-ajax

Comment: your lazy load is set differently on the other pages to load when you reach the bottom of the page.  On this you have to click so looks like a possible code error on that page